# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, angular-cli

I have Angular CLI: 9.1.12 installed globaly. If I try to run `ng serve` from my root app it throws the following error:

```
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^8.0.0-beta || >=8.0.0 <9.0.0,
but Angular version 9.1.13 was found instead.
```

I tried to change the global CLI version but without success.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.14.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "common-library": "file:../CommonLibrary/dist/common-library",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ng6-toastr-notifications": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.802.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0-next.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.3.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.36.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly because of angular version and angular cli version.

First of all type `ng v` to check all versions and make them match major versions.

Also if you want to run cli from your project specific cli, then just type

`npm run start`, instead of `ng serve`.

Comment: `ng v` from my app shows `Angular/CLI 8.3.29`. I tried matching the global version but it gives the same error running ng serve

Comment: Update your cli version to 9.x.x and run `npm start` instead of `ng serve`

Comment: Are you talking about the local version? Do you know the command?

Comment: Yes. just do `npm install @angular/cli@9.1.13` and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks that changing the CLI version produced tons of node_module errors `An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.`